# Apache HttpClient 4.3 SocketConfig.getSoTimeout() vs RequestConfig.getSocketTimeout()

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

When building a `CloseableHttpClient` in Apache HttpClient 4.3, I can use

```
SocketConfig.custom().setSoTimeout(soTimeout).build()
```

and send it to the `setDefaultSocketConfig()` method of my connection manager.

I can also use

```
RequestConfig.custom().setSocketTimeout(socketTimeout).build()
```

and send it to the `setDefaultRequestConfig()` method of my http client builder.

Will these have the same end effect or different end effects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Socket timeout in `SocketConfig` represents the default value applied to newly created connections. This value can be overwritten for individual requests by setting a non zero value of socket timeout in `RequestConfig`.

Comment: So what happens if there's both a `SocketConfig` and a *default* `RequestConfig`?

Comment: SocketConfig applies only when new sockets are created. RequestConfig socket timeout value always overwrites that set at construction time.

Comment: To state in other words, it appears that SocketConfig's socket timeout _is still used_ for initial socket creation regardless of RequestConfig's socket timeout. We discovered an issue that appears to require socket timeouts on both SocketConfig and RequestConfig.

Comment: The socketTimeout value is seconds / milliseconds ? is quite unclear to me from the java docs, as it is not specified.

Comment: @RaduToader Socket timeouts are always in milliseconds.

Comment: hi @Stano, I think I am facing the same issue. However I do not understand what is causing the issue. Can you please elaborate?!