# Why Apache HttpClient 4.5.2 is does not timeout on non responsive http proxy but block on stream read insteed?

Tags: java, proxy, apache-httpclient-4.x

In short: I want to test some http proxies. I have run into a single proxy that seems to be unresponsive, however HttpClient is does not timeout like it should. Stacktrace shows that app is blocked on read method. It should timeout IMHO but it is not. In general code is tested and works fine in plenty of other cases (including timeouts, exceptions etc.)

How I configure my request (yes, I use those on request execution):

```
requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setSocketTimeout(2000)
        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(1000)
        .setConnectTimeout(5000);

RequestConfig config = requestConfig.setProxy(proxyHost).build();
context.setRequestConfig(config);
```

What HttpClient is doing - request is sent but no response:

```
09:55:06.719 [ProxyPool-ScheduledWorkers-pool-3-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: default
09:55:06.720 [ProxyPool-ScheduledWorkers-pool-3-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
09:55:06.721 [ProxyPool-ScheduledWorkers-pool-3-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: {tls}->http://84.28.86.73:80->https://api.ipify.org:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
09:55:06.722 [ProxyPool-ScheduledWorkers-pool-3-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: 19][route: {tls}->http://84.28.86.73:80->https://api.ipify.org:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
09:55:06.723 [ProxyPool-ScheduledWorkers-pool-3-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.h.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Opening connection {tls}->http://84.28.86.73:80->https://api.ipify.org:443
09:55:06.723 [ProxyPool-ScheduledWorkers-pool-3-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to /84.28.86.73:80
09:55:06.786 [ProxyPool-ScheduledWorkers-pool-3-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connection established 192.168.2.144:31914<->84.28.86.73:80
09:55:06.787 [ProxyPool-ScheduledWorkers-pool-3-thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-19 >> CONNECT api.ipify.org:443 HTTP/1.1
09:55:06.787 [ProxyPool-ScheduledWorkers-pool-3-thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-19 >> Host: api.ipify.org
09:55:06.788 [ProxyPool-ScheduledWorkers-pool-3-thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-19 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_66)
09:55:06.788 [ProxyPool-ScheduledWorkers-pool-3-thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-19 >> "CONNECT api.ipify.org:443 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
09:55:06.788 [ProxyPool-ScheduledWorkers-pool-3-thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-19 >> "Host: api.ipify.org[\r][\n]"
09:55:06.789 [ProxyPool-ScheduledWorkers-pool-3-thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-19 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_66)[\r][\n]"
09:55:06.789 [ProxyPool-ScheduledWorkers-pool-3-thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-19 >> "[\r][\n]"
```

Here is the stackrace where connection is blocked

```
Thread [ProxyPool-ScheduledWorkers-pool-3-thread-1] (Suspended) 
SocketInputStream.socketRead0(FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) line: not available [native method]    
SocketInputStream.socketRead(FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) line: not available 
SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int, int) line: not available   
SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) line: not available    
LoggingInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) line: 87  
SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(byte[], int, int) line: 139   
SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer() line: 155   
SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(CharArrayBuffer) line: 284  
DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(SessionInputBuffer) line: 140   
DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(SessionInputBuffer) line: 57    
DefaultHttpResponseParser(AbstractMessageParser<T>).parse() line: 261   
LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection(DefaultBHttpClientConnection).receiveResponseHeader() line: 165  
CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader() line: 167    
HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequest, HttpClientConnection, HttpContext) line: 272 
HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequest, HttpClientConnection, HttpContext) line: 124   
MainClientExec.createTunnelToTarget(AuthState, HttpClientConnection, HttpRoute, HttpRequest, HttpClientContext) line: 472   
MainClientExec.establishRoute(AuthState, HttpClientConnection, HttpRoute, HttpRequest, HttpClientContext) line: 397 
MainClientExec.execute(HttpRoute, HttpRequestWrapper, HttpClientContext, HttpExecutionAware) line: 236  
ProtocolExec.execute(HttpRoute, HttpRequestWrapper, HttpClientContext, HttpExecutionAware) line: 184    
RedirectExec.execute(HttpRoute, HttpRequestWrapper, HttpClientContext, HttpExecutionAware) line: 110    
InternalHttpClient.doExecute(HttpHost, HttpRequest, HttpContext) line: 184  
InternalHttpClient(CloseableHttpClient).execute(HttpUriRequest, HttpContext) line: 82   
InternalHttpClient(CloseableHttpClient).execute(HttpUriRequest, HttpContext) line: 55   
Ipify.getExternalIp(HttpClient, RequestConfig, HttpContext) line: 48    
Ipify.getExternalIp(HttpClient, HttpContext) line: 33   
<obsolete method in<unknown declaring type>>    
ProxyTester.isHttpsProxyValidQuiet(HttpsProxyHost) line: 105    
FetchProxiesFromSourceTask.run() line: 72   
Executors$RunnableAdapter<T>.call() line: not available 
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask<V>(FutureTask<V>).runAndReset() line: not available 
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask<V>.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask) line: not available  
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask<V>.run() line: not available    
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(ThreadPoolExecutor).runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) line: not available    
ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: not available 
Thread.run() line: not available
```

EDIT: Honorable mention:
[setting socket timeout in both RequestConfig and SocketConfig works differently for HTTP and HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27833836/setting-socket-timeout-in-both-requestconfig-and-socketconfig-works-differently)

Looks like a design flaw to me as there is no way to set `soTimeout` prior SSL handshake on request basis.

And reported bug here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1478